# operator overloading function called when constructing a thread

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Lately, I came across with this code as part of **studying threading**, and there is a part which I can't understand.
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo() { std::cout << "foo()\n"; }
void bar() { std::cout << "bar()\n"; }

class task
{
 public:
     task() { cout << "task constructor\n"; }

     void operator()() const
     {
        cout << "operator()\n";
        foo();
        bar();
     }
};

int main()
{
   task tsk;
   std::thread t(tsk);
   t.join();
   return 0;
}
```

the part I didn't understand was after creating "tsk" object. when constructing the "t" thread `std::thread t(tsk);`
**the operator overload function was called**.
 I didn't understand why the operator overloading "()" was called and when this happened. 
I will be really greatful if anyone can explain me this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` takes a callable object to execute. When you overload `operator()()`, you are making your `task` object callable.

Example:

```
tsk();
// Output
task constructor
operator()
foo()
bar()
```

Remove your definition of `operator()()`...

```
tsk();
// Output
error: type 'task' does not provide a call operator
```

`std::thread t(tsk);` won't even compile unless `task` is a callable object.

If you're asking *why* it behaves this way, we take a look to [n3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) (C++11 draft standard) [thread.thread.constr]. The constructor `std::thread t(tsk);` is calling is:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

This constructor executes `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY( std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY(std::forward<Args>(args))...)`. In other words, it calls `f(arg1, arg2, arg3...)`.

If you want unofficial documentation that says it better than I do, try [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).